# Create Blazor Server Login Page to fetch Jwt

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-authentication

We have a Blazor server app which is packaged as an electron desktop app.

Identity cannot reside alongside the app it must be remote so I decided to use Jwt. I have created a Jwt server & have JwtBearer middleware enabled in the Blazor server app startup.cs (see code).

At present we can attach a Jwt to context.Token manually in 'JwtBearerEvents --> OnMessageReceived' and middleware picks this up so we can use [Authorize] & also include Policies [Authorize(Policy="account_write")] this works great.

The Jwt is created manually in Postman (calling our Jwt server and the pasting in the result - see code) as I cannot figure out how to have a login page that uses the Un/Pw to fetch a Jwt from the server.

I appreciate HTTP is only availabe for a few requests before SignalR kicks in, and that is the crux of the problem but im hoping there is a way around this.

I thought I could use a combination of Blazor and razor pages, ie login page is cshtml and saves token to LocalStorage or Cookie then we start blazor (Javascript autostart off for the blazor.server.js) & read the cookie - I have not been able to get this to work as I cannot get razor and cshtml working together.

Any ideas how can I create a login page to fetch the Jwt & attach it to the context?

`````
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,

        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            // Is token in Querystring?
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            Debug.WriteLine($"JwtBearer - OnMessageReceived  -  access_token in QS: {ShorterJWT(accessToken)}");

            //
            // Attach the token manually  
            //

            // Jwt fetched manually using Postman - 10 year 
            accessToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjNjMzIxMjI2LTFhNGYtNGQ3NS1iZjM1LTIwYjQ1NmVlYmYzOSIsImJvb2tlciI6InRydWUiLCJuYW1lIjoiQm9iIENyYXRjaGV0IiwibmJmIjoxNjI5NzM3MTk4LCJleHAiOjE5NDUyNjk5OTgsImlhdCI6MTYyOTczNzE5OH0.N9HUFM3zIl9BkoPJlPj_WQIUhhQ2Rk53ymEEm42LTD4";

            context.Token = accessToken;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});````
`````

Comment: Did you take the token generated by another JWT project and manually put it into your current project for verification?

Comment: @Chaodeng Sort of, its a separate Jwt project that is part of this solution. So we check un/pw and issue a Jwt, where it is used in this blazor server project. Both Jwt server & this  blazor server client share the same Secret key.